# Ошибка соединения с базой из backend (из frontend работает отлично)

Tags: yii2

Приветствую всех.
Есть advanced-приложение. В frontend и backend настройки к базе одинаковые и хранятся в /common/config/main.php и /common/config/main.local.php
В /frontend/config/main.php и /backend/config/main.php (main и main-local) никаких настроек базы нет.

Локально все работает. Но когда скопировал на сервер, то при попытке обращении к БД backend-отказывается работать и пишет ошибку (frontend работает отлично):

> Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory ↵ Caused by:
>   PDOException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>
> in
>   /homepages/9/d600525307/htdocs/website/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php
>   at line 600

Из-за чего такое? Единственный момент: таблица к которой обращается frontend с подчеркиванием имеет вид: name_name, соответственно модель ActiveRecord для работы с ней называется NameName. Пробовал убирать подчеркивание в названии таблицы - все то же самое.
Перерыл в гугле многие форумы и не нашем ответа на вопрос. Из-за чего такое может быть?

Comment: Что у вас стоит в config/db.php? 127.0.0.1? Если да, то смените на localhost(или ip, который у вас)

Comment: composer up на сервере делали?